# GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService leads to 500 server error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am working on an app which uses GAE and GCS serverside. Among other things I can upload pictures and store their publicUrl in a google mysql database. Today I tried to use .secureUrl(true) when getting those publicUrls and since then I get a 500 server error when sending post requests.

I can break it down to the following code snippet:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
ServletException {


    // create Writer for response
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("application/json");

    // create Database Connection url with name database, username and password
    String mysqlUrl = System.getProperty("cloudsql");

    // get 'operation' parameter to determine further action
    String operation = request.getParameter("operation");
    if (operation == null){ operation = "getFav"; }


    GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
```

When I dont comment out the last line where gcsService is set, every post request sent from my phone is answered with a 500 server error. If I make the line a comment, everything (except for the parts where gcs is used) works perfectly. Checking out the Google console, I get the following message:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty

```
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createRawGcsService (GcsServiceFactory.java:57)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService (GcsServiceFactory.java:44)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService (GcsServiceFactory.java:40)
    at net.xyz.yzxI.HelloAppEngine.<init> (HelloAppEngine.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance (ContextHandler.java:2481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet (ServletContextHandler.java:1327)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance (ServletHolder.java:1285)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet (ServletHolder.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet (ServletHolder.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.ensureInstance (ServletHolder.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.prepare (ServletHolder.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle (Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:320)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnection.handle (RpcConnection.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.RpcConnector.serviceRequest (RpcConnector.java:81)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest (JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:108)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest (JavaRuntime.java:680)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest (JavaRuntime.java:642)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:612)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run (JavaRuntime.java:806)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run (ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

It drives me crazy: Even if I dont use the gcs at all, just trying to set it up breaks the app. I have like no clue where to look at, so hopefully someone else has had similar experiences or knows what to check.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven to handle dependencies this error may be due to a "provided" in the com.google.appengine dependency. Remove that line in pom.xml so Maven will include app engine sdk in the compiled project.

Before:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.63</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

After:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.63</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right sir, it had to do with dependencies and the specific depency you mentioned was the problem. I already figured out that writing "<artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>" instead of "<artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>" solved it, even with "provided". What I dont understand though: Until when I posted my problem it worked absolutely perfect. I didnt change a thing, but all of a suddend this artifactiD had to be changed. As far as I remember, I simply copied everything from google docs. Am I missing s.thing or did Google change this without notifying?

Comment: without being sure; perhaps "appengine-api-1.0-sdk" is no longer "provided" on app engine - but "appengine-maven-plugin" is (and contains the needed classes)